# Ubuntu 18.04 abruptly crashing

Tags: 18.04, power-management, shutdown, battery, crash

I'm recently experiencing a strange issue. I have a laptop (Acer Aspire E 15 serie) on which I installed Ubuntu 18.04

It worked flawlessly for a year, then it's a month since it abruptly shuts down (no poweroff message, the screen just goes black and the computer stops working) and I need to start it manually.

It usually happens when the electric charger is disconnected, even if the battery is over 90%.

What can I do? I use it for works.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like your cpu is overheating. can you check the temperature?

Comment: I once experienced crash every 5-10 minutes, but according to sensors CPU's temperature was ok, far far below the boiling point

Comment: Are you sure your battery is ok? How old is it? If this happens often you can also try to leave it for a while on live cd (run it from pendrive) and check if this happens too. Another thing you may try is to disable acpi through grub settings with acpi=off flag.

Comment: The battery is a year old. Yes, I would try asap, thanks for the suggestion